# Ошибка при подключение php (PDO) к MySQL [caching_sha2_password]

Tags: php, mysql, apache, pdo, xampp

Подключил `Apache`, `MySQL` в `XAMPP` - всё отлично.

Пытаюсь подключиться к базе данных через `php`, используя `PDO`. Вот код:

```
<?php

$driver  = 'mysql';
$host    = 'localhost';
$db_name = 'kontora';
$db_pass = 'password123';
$db_user = 'admin';
$charset = 'utf8';
$options = [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION];

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("$driver:host=$host;dbname=$db_name;charset=$charset", $db_user, $db_pass, $options);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die($e);
}
```

Все данные верны, как я всё вводил (имя дб, юзер и т.д.).

В конце концов выдаёт ошибку:

> PDOException: PDO::__construct(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password] in D:\xampp\htdocs\kontora\index.php:12 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\kontora\index.php(12): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'admin', 'password123', Array) #1 {main} Next PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client in D:\xampp\htdocs\kontora\index.php:12 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\kontora\index.php(12): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'admin', 'password123', Array) #1 {main}

Что делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вся проблема состояла в указании порта сервера. Так как это необязательный параметр, то у него есть свой стандарт, который как раз-таки у меня был отредактирован (в ходе исправления другой ошибки).

Вот код который у меня получился:

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;port=3307;dbname=kontora;charset=utf8";

$options = [
      PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
      PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
    ];

$pdo = new PDO($dsn, 'admin', 'password123', $options);
```

Я также опустил блок `try...catch...` - в официальной документации указано, что `PDO` может сам вывести возникшее исключение.

Answer (score 2):

> Начиная с MySQL 8.0.4, мы меняем плагин аутентификации по умолчанию
>   для сервера MySQL с mysql_native_password на caching_sha2_password.
>   Соответственно, libmysqlclient теперь будет использовать
>   caching_sha2_password как механизм аутентификации по умолчанию.

[Cсылка на источник](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-4-new-default-authentication-plugin-caching_sha2_password/)

В случае, если вы хотите использовать прежний способ аутентификации это возможно сделать добавив нового пользователя. Зайдите в консоль mysql и выполните команду:

```
CREATE USER user@localhost identified with mysql_native_password by 'password';
```

Теперь вы сможете подключиться пользователем `user` c паролем `password`

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'by 'password'' at line 1

Comment: также попробовал дописать одинарные кавычки у `user` и у `localhost` - не помогает